# Struts2 populate tag select drop down list

Tags: java, select, struts2, tags

I try to populate select drop down list with Struts but it's not working:

I have my action class :

private Integer anneeResultat;

```
    private List<AnneeResultat> anneeResultatList = new ArrayList<AnneeResultat>();


public Integer getAnneeResultat() {

        return anneeResultat;
    }
    public void setAnneeResultat(Integer anneeResultat) {
        this.anneeResultat = anneeResultat;
    }


public List<AnneeResultat> getAnneeResultatList() {
    this.anneeResultatList.add(new AnneeResultat(2005,"2005"));
    this.anneeResultatList.add(new AnneeResultat(2006,"2006"));
    this.anneeResultatList.add(new AnneeResultat(2007,"2007"));
    this.anneeResultatList.add(new AnneeResultat(2008,"2008"));
    this.anneeResultatList.add(new AnneeResultat(2009,"2009"));
    this.anneeResultatList.add(new AnneeResultat(2010,"2010"));
    this.anneeResultatList.add(new AnneeResultat(2011,"2011"));
        return this.anneeResultatList;
    }
    public void setAnneeResultatsList(List<AnneeResultat> anneeResultatList) {
        this.anneeResultatList = anneeResultatList;
    }
    public String execute(){
    return SUCCESS;
    }
```

Here is the class AnneeResultat:

```
public class AnneeResultat {
     private Integer keyAnnee;  
     private String valueAnnee;         
    public AnneeResultat() {    
    }
    public AnneeResultat(Integer key, String value) {
        super();
        this.keyAnnee = key;
        this.valueAnnee = value;
    }
    public Integer getKey() {
        return keyAnnee;
    }
    public void setKey(Integer key) {
        this.keyAnnee = key;
    }
    public String getValue() {
        return valueAnnee;
    }
    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.valueAnnee = value;
    }   
}
```

Here is select tag as used on my jsp page. I use tiles on my page. Here is my first version on my page:

```
<s:select name="anneeResultat" label="Année de résultats" list="anneeResultatList" listKey="keyAnnee" listValue="valueAnnee"></s:select>
```

The result is that in my page the select tag generate a select box with empty element. I can't see value on the select box. No value is visible.
The generated code is :

```
<select name="anneeResultat" id="choices_anneeResultat">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value=""></option>
</select>
```

When i used the following select tag :

```
<s:select name="anneeResultat" label="Année de résultats" list="anneeResultatList" key="keyAnnee" value="valueAnnee"></s:select>
```

Hashcode is printed on select box list.

The generated code is :

```
<select name="anneeResultat" id="choices_anneeResultat">
    <option value="fr.si2m.occ.dao.model.ui.AnneeResultat@1b209bc">fr.si2m.occ.dao.model.ui.AnneeResultat@1b209bc</option>
    <option value="fr.si2m.occ.dao.model.ui.AnneeResultat@19d5723">fr.si2m.occ.dao.model.ui.AnneeResultat@19d5723</option>
    <option value="fr.si2m.occ.dao.model.ui.AnneeResultat@c3bba9">fr.si2m.occ.dao.model.ui.AnneeResultat@c3bba9</option>
    <option value="fr.si2m.occ.dao.model.ui.AnneeResultat@5554a3">fr.si2m.occ.dao.model.ui.AnneeResultat@5554a3</option>
    <option value="fr.si2m.occ.dao.model.ui.AnneeResultat@27b326">fr.si2m.occ.dao.model.ui.AnneeResultat@27b326</option>
    <option value="fr.si2m.occ.dao.model.ui.AnneeResultat@6283de">fr.si2m.occ.dao.model.ui.AnneeResultat@6283de</option>
    <option value="fr.si2m.occ.dao.model.ui.AnneeResultat@1bf7b9c">fr.si2m.occ.dao.model.ui.AnneeResultat@1bf7b9c</option>
</select>
```

I don't know how to do to solve this problem. If someone has some ideas, it will welcome !

Answer (score 2):

Just delete the constructor from `AnneeResultat` and use the below select tag in your JSP.

```
<s:select name="anneeResultat" label="Année de résultats" 
    list="anneeResultatList" key="keyAnnee" value="valueAnnee"></s:select>
```

Answer (score 2):

use "listValue" for the column you want to display.

`<s:select name="anneeResultat" label="Année de résultats" list="anneeResultatList" key="keyAnnee" listValue="valueAnnee"></s:select>`

Answer (score 0):

The "listKey=foo" expects a getter with the same name, but named with "get" appended to the value, e.g. getFoo().

Either change your getter name to "getKeyAnnee" or change the listKey to "key"